# What is the best way to use one layout for different pages? (without database)

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a website and I have a layout for at least 20 services which are only different in description and image. I'm trying to find a way to implement one layout and add data for a specific link and I don't want to use a database because the data isn't important to save. Is there another way or I have to use 20 blades that extend one layout?

Comment: Just use the default app.layout from laravel and make those pages with only that data which is different... you can use slots for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can have an array like this that you will pass to a layout

   `$servicesLayout = [
       'service_1' => [
           'description' => 'Service 1 description',
           'image' => 'www.host.com/assets/img/section_1.jpg'],
       'service_2' => [
           'description' => 'Service 2 description',
           'image' => 'www.host.com/assets/img/section_2.jpg']
   ];`
2. Now when viewing a section, you pass the section key for example 'section_1' to the layout
3. To display section description in layout

`{{$servicesLayout['service_1']['description']}}`